# C passing 2D subset of 3D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, 3d

I have a 3D array defined as

```
double ***array
```

which is dynamically allocated memory. I'm sure the allocation is correct. The array looks something like this

```
array[TDIM][YDIM][XDIM]
```

My question is about passing/working with the array. The function declaration is

```
void fun(double ***array);
```

Generally, I would make a function call and pass the array as

```
fun(array)
```

where inside the function I can change the values. For example

```
array[0][10][10] = 2.29;
```

which works as intended. What if I have a function where I want to work on only one "layer" of the array instead of passing the entire array...say where TDIM == 4...how do I pass that argument? What does the function declaration look like? How to I change values within the function being called?

I've tried something like this and it compiles but something seems fishy

```
void fun(double **array)    // function declaration
fun(array[4])               // function call
array[10][10] = 2.29;       // Inside the function, change array[4][10][10] to 2.29
```

I just want to work on one 2D-layer of the 3D array inside the function and not have to pass the entire 3D array, if that makes sense. Can I do this directly, or do I have to create a temporary array to store the 2D-layer and work with that? Could use some input.

EDIT: Added sample code to further illustrate. Are both approaches the same? I think I'm having difficulty with "fun2" approach:

```
void fun(double ***array);  // Declaration
void fun2(double **array);  // Declaration

int main()
{
    double ***array
    int XDIM=10,YDIM=10,TDIM=2;

    allocate3d(&array,XDIM,YDIM,TDIM); // This works fine
    fun(array);
    fun2(array[0]);
}

void fun(double ***array)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
        {
            array[0][j][i] = 2.29;
        }
    }
}

void fun2(double **array)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
        {
            array[j][i] = 2.29;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your solution? It seems fine to me.

Comment: I've added a sample code to the original post

Comment: 0) `allocate3d(array,XDIM,YDIM,TDIM);` wrong. 1) `void fun(array)` wrong.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY: "allocate3d" is a function I have not shown here. I know it works. As for the function arguments, I fixed those.

Comment: E.g `Type ***p;`, `void func(Type ***p,...){ p = malloc(...);}`, call `func(p, ...);` , So `p` not change. [DEMO](http://ideone.com/vnOQv5)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing what you're saying. I allocate the 3D array in the scope of main. Then pass it to the functions. The allocation function is fine. If I want to fill the array within the functions, is "fun" the same as "fun2"? I want "fun2" to operate on a 2D-slice of the 3D array but I'm not sure if I'm passing the slice correct, declaring the function "fun2" correct, and filling the array in "fun2" correctly. I'm 99% sure "fun" is correct.

Comment: Now likely to operate. also `YDIM` and `XDIM` Are these the global variable?

Comment: Yes they are global. I didn't expect the example to work. It was more of an illustrative example comparing calls to "fun" and "fun2". Notice how one takes the whole array, while the other takes a slice. I'm wondering if the syntax is correct for the "fun2" call and achieves the same thing as the "fun" call.

Comment: in general, if your passing the whole 3d array, then something is VERY wrong with your code.  However, you could easily pass a pointer to the whole array, (***array) and a second parameter that indicates which layer (first dimension of the array) that the called function is to manipulate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better that you provide a working example.. there are many missing pieces that could be wrong in some way (as for instance the variables `XDIM`, `YDIM`, ..). It is difficult to understand what you are attempting to do.

Assuming that the task of `fun` and `fun2` is to write the value `2.29` in a user-passed cell, then your `fun` method does not make a lot of sense.. How do you pass the index? you used `0` inside the method.. What about this change:

```
void fun(double ***array, int idx)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < YDIM; j++)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < XDIM; i++)
        {
            array[idx][j][i] = 2.29;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT after comment: A three-dimensional array looks like an array of 2d-arrays, and it's  contiguously in memory:

```
int array3d[2][2][2] = {{{0, 1}, {2, 3}},{{4, 5}, {6, 8}}};
```

is in memory like this:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

and it is exactly the same as declaring:

```
int array1d[8] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
```

Thus, your approach is correct since you are changing the same memory location.

Comment: I just used the 0 for comparison purposes. You see in "fun" I put array[0][j][i] where as in the call to "fun2" I pass array[0]. The underlying reason I asked this question is that I have numerous functions that look like "fun2" that originally operated on 2D arrays, but I've recently changed to using 3D arrays and don't want have to change all the functions in the program. If I can, I just want to pull a slice of the 3D array and use existing 2D functions. I suppose I could use a temp variable, but I thought I could simply pass the slice as I've shown in the "fun2" call?

Comment: @ThatRightJack Did it solve your doubt? if not, please provide an example that does not work as you expect..

Comment: I guess it was right....turns out I had an error using memcpy within the function. I'm going to start a new question to address this issue

Answer (score 1):

You do it just how you'd expect. Your original program seems to have some issues where you're assuming `XDIM` and `YDIM` to be globals, but they appear not to be.

This will work as you expect:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct tda {
    double *** data;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
};

struct tda * tda_allocate(const int x, const int y, const int z);
void tda_destroy(struct tda * array);
void tda_fill_level(double ** data, const int x, const int y,
                    const double value);
void tda_print(struct tda * array);

int main(void)
{
    struct tda * array = tda_allocate(3, 2, 2);

    for ( int i = 0; i < array->x; ++i ) {
        tda_fill_level(array->data[i], array->y, array->z, i + 1);
    }

    tda_print(array);
    tda_destroy(array);

    return 0;
}

struct tda * tda_allocate(const int x, const int y, const int z)
{
    struct tda * new_array = malloc(sizeof *new_array);
    if ( !new_array ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double *** new_data = malloc(x * sizeof *new_data);
    if ( !new_data ) {
        perror("couldn't allocate memory");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < x; ++i ) {
        new_data[i] = malloc(y * sizeof *new_data[i]);
        if ( !new_data[i] ) {
            perror("couldn't allocate memory");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        for ( int j = 0; j < y; ++j ) {
            new_data[i][j] = malloc(z * sizeof *new_data[i][j]);
            if ( !new_data[i][j] ) {
                perror("couldn't allocate memory");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
    }

    new_array->data = new_data;
    new_array->x = x;
    new_array->y = y;
    new_array->z = z;

    return new_array;
}

void tda_destroy(struct tda * array)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array->x; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < array->y; ++j ) {
            free(array->data[i][j]);
        }
        free(array->data[i]);
    }
    free(array->data);
    free(array);
}


void tda_fill_level(double ** data, const int x, const int y,
                    const double value)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < x; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < y; ++j ) {
            data[i][j] = value;
        }
    }
}

void tda_print(struct tda * array)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < array->x; ++i ) {
        for ( int j = 0; j < array->y; ++j ) {
            for ( int k = 0; k < array->z; ++k ) {
                printf("%2d,%2d,%2d: %f\n", i, j, k, array->data[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with output:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./tda
 0, 0, 0: 1.000000
 0, 0, 1: 1.000000
 0, 1, 0: 1.000000
 0, 1, 1: 1.000000
 1, 0, 0: 2.000000
 1, 0, 1: 2.000000
 1, 1, 0: 2.000000
 1, 1, 1: 2.000000
 2, 0, 0: 3.000000
 2, 0, 1: 3.000000
 2, 1, 0: 3.000000
 2, 1, 1: 3.000000
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```